# Errors giving ... is not a number when Trying to minimise a function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I'm trying to minimising the following equation wrt ssq and mq

```
s1 = 2;
m1 = 2;
s2 = 4;
m2 = 4;
s3 = 3;
m3 = 3;
d1 = ssq^2/(2*s1^2) + mq^2/(2*s1^2) + m1^2/(2*s1^2) - 
   2*mq*m1/(2*s1^2) + log[s1/ssq] - 0.5;
d2 = ssq^2/(2*s2^2) + mq^2/(2*s2^2) + m2^2/(2*s2^2) - 
   2*mq*m2/(2*s2^2) + log[s2/ssq] - 0.5;
d3 = ssq^2/(2*s3^2) + mq^2/(2*s3^2) + m3^2/(2*s3^2) - 
   2*mq*m3/(2*s3^2) + log[s3/ssq] - 0.5;
f[ssq_, mq_] := -log[0.3*E^(-d1) + 0.3*E^(-d2) + 0.4*E^(-d3)]

Minimize[{f[ssq, mq], { ssq > 0 && mq > 0}}, {ssq, mq}]
```

but it returns the following error:

```
NMaximize::nnum: The function value -log[0.3 E^(0.153262 -log[1.20227])+0.4 E^(0.281297 -log[1.80341])+0.3 E^(0.278143 -log[2.40455])] is not a number at {mq,ssq} = {1.91862,1.66351}.
```

I don't think it make a lot of sense because `log[0.3 E^(0.153262 -log[1.20227])+0.4 E^(0.281297 -log[1.80341])+0.3 E^(0.278143 -log[2.40455])]`  it is actually a number right? Thank you.

Comment: I think it make a lot of sense because `ln` should be `Log`.At the beginning I would read the instructions(Documentation) for use,and I wouldn't have to wonder why something doesn't work.

Comment: Highlight `log` and press `F1` for help. First link is for `Log`, the spelling that @MariuszIwaniuk recommended that you use. All Mathematica built-in functions start with a capital letter. Using the online help is much faster.

Comment: Thank you guys very much, I guess there is no short cut. I will be looking at the document.

Answer (score 0):

I say `Log` not `log`.

```
s1 = 2;
m1 = 2;
s2 = 4;
m2 = 4;
s3 = 3;
m3 = 3;
d1 = ssq^2/(2*s1^2) + mq^2/(2*s1^2) + m1^2/(2*s1^2) - 
2*mq*m1/(2*s1^2) + Log[s1/ssq] - 0.5;
d2 = ssq^2/(2*s2^2) + mq^2/(2*s2^2) + m2^2/(2*s2^2) - 
2*mq*m2/(2*s2^2) + Log[s2/ssq] - 0.5;
d3 = ssq^2/(2*s3^2) + mq^2/(2*s3^2) + m3^2/(2*s3^2) - 
2*mq*m3/(2*s3^2) + Log[s3/ssq] - 0.5;
f[ssq_, mq_] := -Log[0.3*E^(-d1) + 0.3*E^(-d2) + 0.4*E^(-d3)]
Minimize[{f[ssq, mq], {ssq > 0 && mq > 0}}, {ssq, mq}]

(*{0.106404, {ssq -> 2.69988, mq -> 2.60716}}*)
```